# Programmatically enable USB tethering on Android 11

Tags: android, tether

all.

I normally write my own enable/disable usb tether scripts for each Android version I'm on, but 11 got me stumped. It looks like they've moved the tethering modules to a different location and it doesn't appear tethering can be called from "connectivity" (IConnectivityManager.aidl) any longer.

Android 10:

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android10-release/core/java/android/net/IConnectivityManager.aidl

line 113:      int setUsbTethering(boolean enable, String callerPkg);

changes in 11:

https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/modular-system/tethering

"service list" brings up tethering on line 191 with reference to "android.net.ITetheringConnector" which I found below.

Tether-related references in 11:

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/tree/android11-release/packages/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/src/android/net

Line 29  Void setUsbTethering(boolean enable, String callerPkg, IIntResultListener receiver); in the above appears to be the command, but I have no idea what needs to happen in the "IIntResultListener receiver" field. I assume something has to happen in this package first:

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android11-release/packages/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/src/android/net/IIntResultListener.aidl

oneway

```
interface IIntResultListener {  

        void onResult(int resultCode);  
}
```

Too much of a newb to figure this one out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nothing happens in an AIDL; rather search for `implements IIntResultListener`.

Comment: So how do I execute that command to trigger USB Tether to turn on? Like I said, I'm not a programmer, just some guy that likes to mess with Androids here and there. Here's the tethering manager code that's responsible for tethering services: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android11-release/packages/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/src/android/net/TetheringManager.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this one code:
`service call tethering 3 i32 1`
Number of transaction "3" may varry on your phone.

Comment: yeah, this was the code i've used on android 10, but no dice here, as they've changed how tethering gets called.